# Primeng Turbotable component performance issue in IE

Tags: angular, internet-explorer, primeng

I have a turbotable component that is displaying 16 columns, by a variable amount of rows, anywhere from 2 to 7000+. The table is using an ngFor and an ngSwitch to render the right information from the API into the table.

```
<p-table [columns]="cols" [value]="requestTableResults" [reorderableColumns]="true"
  *ngIf="!loadingRequests && requestTableResults.length !== 0">
  <ng-template pTemplate="header" let-columns>
    <tr id="requestTableHeader">
      <th class="padding-header">
        <input type="checkbox" (change)="selectAll($event)" [(ngModel)]="isSelectedAll" />
      </th>
      <th *ngFor="let col of columns" pReorderableColumn class="padding-header">
        {{col.header}} 
      </th>
    </tr>
  </ng-template>
  <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-rowData let-columns="columns">
    <tr class="stripes">
      <td class="padding-data">
        <input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="rowData.isSelected" (change)="selectOne(rowData.isSelected)" />
      </td>
      <td *ngFor="let col of columns" [ngSwitch]="col.field" class="padding-data">
        <span *ngSwitchCase="'status'">
          <div class="badge status-badge">
            <span *ngIf="!rowData.overdue || rowData.status !== 'Open'">
              {{rowData.status}}
            </span>
```

The table renders the information and works extremely well in Chrome, taking ~2.5 seconds to load. In IE though it crawls, taking at  least 9 seconds, sometimes it causes a memory overload, or will pop a long running script error. The performance is better on the dev server as compared to localhost, but is still unacceptable. Is there any way to improve the performance of Turbotable? Is there some underlying issue using an ngFor, ngSwitch and the turbotable component inside of IE?

Comment: 7000+ lines is a lot, especially in combination with the ngSwitch I guess. Virtual scrolling could be a solution, but I am not sure if the PrimeNg Table supports that. I am not really familiar with the components, but does their documentation not include some info for large data sets?

Comment: Not sure if this is the right component, but I found this: https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/blob/master/src/app/components/table/table.ts#L172-L176, which should indicate virtual scrolling is possible for this table + https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/table/scroll

Comment: Pagination is occurring at the server level, so the table is only loading 50 requests at a time and then loading more.

Comment: I don't think the loading is the problem, it's the amount of DOM elements (in combination with the `if` and `switch` stuff); that is why virtual scrolling is interesting. Not sure if you know the concept, but the idea is basically that the element pretends it has all items, but actually only shows a certain amount at the same time (and thus keeping your DOM light)

Comment: So this is what I have found. I got rid of all styles and primeNG and just threw all the stuff into a normal table, and only grab 25 rows from the API, blazing fast in Chrome, slow and freezes in IE.